# SignalR C# client - catch-all route?

Tags: c#, signalr

Is there a way with a C# hub client in SignalR to set up a route which will be called if no other routes match the request?

What I am looking for is when the Hub sends a message to the client, but that route simply does not exist.  In this case I want the client to log what the name of that event was.

Comment: Have you tried `Connection.Received` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.connection.received(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: That does not tell me whether the message was handles though. I really want to know when a message was not handled.